# What is the difference in getting the root view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout, rootview

What is the difference b/w these two:

```
FrameLayout customView = (FrameLayout) view.getRootView();  


FrameLayout customView = (FrameLayout) activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
```

Answer (score 2):

activity.getWindow().getDecorView(); it gives refernce to the outermost layout... while view.getRootView() gives the refernce to the layout containing the view..

Answer (score 0):

I think getRootView() finds the topmost view in the current ViewGroup where getDecorView returns an instance of all the items of ViewGroup.